# Most efficient way to store IP Address in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ip-address

What is the most efficient way to store and retrieve IP addresses in MySQL?  Right now I'm doing:

```
SELECT * FROM logins WHERE ip = '1.2.3.4'
```

Where ip is a `VARCHAR(15)` field.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Ok, so your program is broken or does not work at all with IPv6... sigh.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

For [IPv4 addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4), you may want to store them as an `int unsigned` and use the [`INET_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) and [`INET_NTOA()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) functions to return the IP address from its numeric value, and vice versa.

Example:

```
SELECT INET_ATON('127.0.0.1');

+------------------------+
| INET_ATON('127.0.0.1') |
+------------------------+
|             2130706433 | 
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


SELECT INET_NTOA('2130706433');

+-------------------------+
| INET_NTOA('2130706433') |
+-------------------------+
| 127.0.0.1               | 
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: you wouldn't store as `INT` but `INT UNSIGNED`. i like the use of purposely inbuilt functions though. +1

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if there is a python function for this?

Comment: @ensnare: Yes, check this: http://snipplr.com/view/14807/convert-ip-to-int-and-int-to-ip/.

Comment: What about IPv6?

Comment: For **IPv6** and **IPv4** use function [INET6_ATON()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet6-aton)

Comment: For IPv6 I got NULL while selecting IP address, later I understood to use INET6_NTOA with HEX() and UNHEX() functions for readability and also, when using this functions, query ignored index on this column. I put my thoughts here http://www.rathishkumar.in/2017/08/how-to-store-ip-address-in-mysql.html

Comment: Can you please update your answer to use `INET6_ATON()` ? or you don't recommend `INET6_ATON()` ?

Comment: @rathishDBA it's blob, not null

Comment: @CMCDragonkai the most efficient storage for both ipv4 and ipv6 is probably VARBINARY(16), i'm not 100% sure but it would make sense =/ (an ipv4 address is 4 bytes long, and an ipv6 address is 16 bytes)

Answer (score 64):

If you only want to store IPv4 addresses, then you can store them in a 32-bit integer field.

If you want to support IPv6 as well, then a string is probably the most easy-to-read/use way (though you could technically store them in a 16-byte `VARBINARY()` field, it would be annoying trying to generate SQL statements to select by IP address "by hand")

Comment: +1: the only answer that predicts usage of IPv6

Comment: Just when using IPV6 the functions are different ( INET6_ATON(ip) ).  
IPV4 needs  VARBINARY(4) and IPV6 would need  VARBINARY(16) (which of course works for V4 addresses as well).
You can convert a V4 IP (INT) to a compatible format like this: INET6_ATON(INET_NTOA(ip))

Comment: `INET6_ATON('172.32.x.x')` can convert both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses into `blob`. The same can be converted back using `INET6_NTOA`. No need to do `INET6_ATON(INET_NTOA(ipv4))` as stated by @John

Comment: @TirthaR correction: not into `BLOB`, but into `VARBINARY(16)` :)

Answer (score 6):

Whatever is easiest for you to work with.  The size or speed issue is not an issue until you know it is an issue by profiling.  In some cases, a string might be easier to work with if you need to do partial matching.  But as a space or performance issue, don't worry about it unless you have real cause to worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing is to make sure that column is indexed. This could make a huge difference to queries based on IP address.

Comment: My understanding is that indexes on a varchar are of limited assistance.

Comment: @Josiah what makes u say that?

Answer (score 1):

maybe store the integer value directly in an integer field?  An IP address is basically 4 "shorts".

Check it out: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/945-converting-a-32-bit-integer-into-ip

Comment: so he would store it in four fields? and they would be bytes, no? 2^8 everytime

Alternatively, he could convert them to decimal numbers and store the decimal, although that would be a larger field, it would be a single field.

Comment: A more appropriate vernacular would be to say that an IP address is 4 bytes.

Comment: I got the gist. Brian's saying that conceptually an int is made up of four shorts. A short is a byte. An int is 4 bytes. As said elsewhere on this page, it needs to be an unsigned int.