# Registration script.php does not work

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a registration script that doesn't work. It used to work but then suddenly it stopped working. I dont know what I've done or what happend. I have tried for like an hour now to find out where the problem is, but I can't seem to find it.

What happens? When I click register I don't get any errors but it doesn't upload to the database:

When I type: `$res = mysql_query($query) or die ("ERROR");` it displays `ERROR` so I think it's related to that code:

```
//=============Configuring Server and Database=======
$host        =    'localhost';
$user        =    'root';
$password    =    '';
//=============Data Base Information=================
$database    =    'login';

$conn        =    mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die('Server Information is not Correct'); //Establish Connection with Server
mysql_select_db($database,$conn) or die('Database Information is not correct');

//===============End Server Configuration============

//=============Starting Registration Script==========

$username    =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

$password    =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass1']);

$email    =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$country    =    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);

$rights    =    '0';

$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


//=============To Encrypt Password===================

//============New Variable of Password is Now with an Encrypted Value========
$query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'"); 
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) 
{ 
    echo 'Username or email already in use.'; 
}
else{
    if(isset($_POST['btnRegister'])) //===When I will Set the Button to 1 or Press Button to register
    {
        $query    =  "insert into users(username,password,email,country,rights,IP,registrated)values('$username','$password','$email','$country',$rights,$IP,NOW())" ;
        $res    =    mysql_query($query);

        header("location:load.php");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could always try `mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());` and see what the error actually is.

Comment: For one I assume IP is written as a VARCHAR and there are no quotes around this var. in insert statement. `$rights` as well.

Comment: FYI: `mysql_` queries are deprecated and open to SQL injections. Use `mysqli` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting the error because you are missing some quotes in your query for two columns wich really looks like not integers

```
'$email','$country',$rights,$IP,NOW())" //$rights and $ip doesn't have quotes
```

so your query would look like

```
"insert into users(username,password,email,country,rights,IP,registrated)values('$username','$password','$email','$country','$rights','$IP',NOW())"
```

Comment: I cant accept until 5 minutts! But hey! Thanks Fabio! :) It worked... i should have seen that -.- but thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql_error() in order to see what the error message is. If you haven't changed anything in the script then it's either your database structure has changed or your rights have.

Update:

You don't have quotes around your IP value, which is surprising because you said that query worked until now. Anyway you should also consider saving IPs the [RIGHT way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542011/most-efficient-way-to-store-ip-address-in-mysql). Good luck!

Comment: Hello. Thanks for replay PHP_nub-qq. it says:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.100.179,NOW())' at line 1

Comment: ip (probably string) should be quoted.

Comment: You don't have quotes around your IP value, which is surprising because you said that query worked until now. Anyway you should also consider saving IPs the [RIGHT way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542011/most-efficient-way-to-store-ip-address-in-mysql). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! I found it.. i missed some qoutes -.-