# Poll app, avoid multiple votes from same person

Tags: python, django, web

I'm developing a web application with Django which involves some different polls. I display a question followed by some links, and the user clicks on the link which he/she prefers. For example:

```
<p>Which one do you prefer?</p>
<a href="http://domain.com/polls/15/vote/1" >Option 1</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/polls/15/vote/2" >Option 2</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/polls/15/vote/3" >Option 3</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/polls/15/vote/4" >Option 4</a>
```

Each link takes the two numbers `15` which represents the poll number 15 and increases by a vote the option selected, for example `1`.

The problem comes that probably some users would start refreshing the webpage like crazies selecting their option, entering the link `http://domain.com/polls/15/vote/1` in their browser to vote for it a lot of times.

Is there a way to avoid this problem? Should I store the IPs of the voters to the database for `x` time to avoid them voting more than once in `x` time? Wouldn't this be a problem for a lot of users?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how far you want to take it:

- Submit the votes through ajax using POST method so there is no url to access directly from a browser
- Add cookies for those who voted
- Add captcha
- Store IPs ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542011/most-efficient-way-to-store-ip-address-in-mysql) are some suggestions on how to store them efficiently, can also utilize something like Redis if performance is critical, but unless you are building a national voting system you probably would be just fine with a regular table)
- Require registration to vote (registration with email confirmation, registration with facebook account, registration with sms confirmation, and so on)

Also whenever you detected a user has already voted, it could be a smart move to just silently ignore their further votes and pretend that they were accepted, this way they won't try nearly as hard to cheat.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll use POST method and will store the IPs!