# Most efficient way to store IP address in Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

What's the most efficient way to store IP addresses in Amazon's DynamoDB? Another article describes the [Most efficient way to store IP Address in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542011/most-efficient-way-to-store-ip-address-in-mysql) , but it uses a function that's not available in DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1):

The most compact fixed-width representation would be to convert the IPv6 address to its 128-bit (16 byte) representation. DynamoDB supports Binary scalars as an attribute value and Key type, so you could just store this 128 bits in a Binary attribute. This representation may include non-printing and special characters, so you may also consider the fixed (20 byte) width representation using [printing characters in IETF RFC 1924](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1924).